# How to make SetTimer() only send one WM_TIMER message?

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to make `SetTimer()` only send one `WM_TIMER` message and not send a new message every time the specified time elapses? I am currently using `KillTimer()` when I receive a `WM_TIMER` message to stop the timer. Should I continue doing this or there is another way to specify this automatically?

Comment: Easy - don't call Applcation.DoEvents.

Comment: @MartinJames ...are you sure that was intended for this question? It's a C question about raw Windows API functions, not a .net question, and even then, stopping all application events is not the answer; it's likely that this person is making an actual GUI program and just wants to kill his temporary timer, not stop all GUI everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetTimer()` creates a periodic timer only.  The only way to make it a one-shot timer is to kill the timer on the first `WM_TIMER` message, as you are already doing.

Otherwise, change your timer logic so you can use [`CreateWaitableTimer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492.aspx) or [`timeSetEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634.aspx) instead, both of which can create a true one-shot timer.

Answer (score 3):

No, `SetTimer` always repeats. Just kill it in your `WM_TIMER` handler to stop it sending another one.